# how to check if an arr is "wavy"?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16, tasm

my code should check if an ARR is "'wavy" which means the first element is less then the second, the second is greater then the third and same as this till the end of the arr..
but it doesn't work..
here is the code:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG

        
ARR db 3 dup (?)
REZ db 1


CODESEG
start:
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov cx,3                    ;cx=99
    xor ax,ax                    ; ax=0
    xor si,si                    ;si=0
    
    mov [ARR],0
    mov [ARR+1], 1
    mov [ARR+2], 0
    lea bx,[ARR]                 ; bx=offset arr
    L1: cmp cx,1
        je finish
        mov di,cx                ;di=cx (as index)
        neg di                   ;di=-di
        lea si,[bx+di] 
        mov ax,[3+si]
        cmp ax,[4+si]      ; compre the odd vs even index                                                   illegal use of register
        jg wrong                             ; exit if the odd index > even index
        dec cx                               ; cx=cx-1
        cmp cx,0                             ; check if cx=0
        je finish                            ; if  cx=0 finish
        mov di,cx                ;di=cx (as index)
        neg di                   ;di=-di
        lea si,[bx+di] 
        mov ax,[3+si]
        cmp ax,[4+si]        ; compre the even vs odd index                                                 illegal use of register
        jl wrong                            ; exit if the even <odd index
        loop L1                             ; cx=cx-1      if cx!=0 -> jump to L1
    wrong:
        mov [REZ],0
    finish:
    


exit:
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
END start


there is even an example but it doesn't work..
do u know where is the mistake?
```

in the end we should end with res=1 if the arr is "wavy" or if it is not wavy arr=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mismatch between the size of the array elements (**byte**), and the size of the operations that you perform on these elements (**word**).

The definition `ARR db 3 dup (?)` does not match the code `mov ax,[3+si]` `cmp ax,[4+si]`. You need to write `mov AL, [3+si]` `cmp AL, [4+si]` instead.

When the `loop` ends, you should not fall-through into *wrong*, but rather `jmp` to *exit*.

A single address register is enough:

```
  sub  cx, 1
  jbe  exit         ; In case of 0 or 1 array elements
  lea  si, [ARR]
  cld               ; Clear direction flag so LODSB will increment SI
L1:
  lodsb
  cmp  al, [si]
  jg   wrong
  dec  cx
  jz   exit
  lodsb
  cmp  al, [si]
  jl   wrong
  loop L1
  jmp  exit
wrong:
  ...
exit:
  ...
```

---

### It is fascinating to explore alternative solutions

- *Using separate loops for the rising and falling edges of the sawtooth*. Not only are the new loops very short, they can iterate over just one conditional branch thanks to sticking a sentinel to the end of the array. The sentinel is chosen such that the loop has got to end. The position where the loop exit occurs then decides about success or failure:

  ```
    mov  si, offset ARR         ; Address of the array
    mov  cx, ...                ; Number of array elements
    call TestWavy               ; -> AL=[0,1]
    mov  [REZ], al

    ...

  ; IN (cx,si) OUT (al) MOD (ah,bx,cx,dx,si,di)
  TestWavy:
    cld                         ; Clear DF so LODSW will SI++
    mov  bx, cx
    shr  bx, 1
    jz   .fine                  ; In case of 0 or 1 array elements
    lea  di, [si+bx]
    add  di, bx
    mov  dx, [di]               ; Preserve existing bytes
    mov  word ptr [di], 0102h   ; Sentinel for the rising edge
    push si                     ; (1)
  .rise:
    lodsw
    cmp  al, ah
    jng  .rise
    mov  [di], dx               ; Restore the bytes
    cmp  si, di
    pop  si                     ; (1)
    jbe  .wrong

    inc  si                     ; Address of the first falling edge
    dec  cx
    shr  cx, 1
    jz   .fine                  ; In case of 2 array elements
    mov  di, si
    add  di, cx
    add  di, cx
    mov  dx, [di]               ; Preserve existing bytes
    mov  word ptr [di], 0201h   ; Sentinel for the falling edge
  .fall:
    lodsw
    cmp  al, ah
    jnl  .fall
    mov  [di], dx               ; Restore the bytes
    cmp  si, di
    jbe  .wrong
  .fine:
    mov  al, 1
    ret
  .wrong:
    mov  al, 0
    ret
  ```
- *Using the byte-sized registers to the fullest*. This minimizes the number of memory accesses as well as the number of iterations on the loop. Every iteration is guaranteed to be able to perform 8 comparisons, thanks to replicating the last element 7 times. The idea is, that this way, no early exits have to be included. And don't forget that you need to keep 7 unoccupied bytes after the array.

  ```
    mov  si, offset ARR         ; Address of the array
    mov  cx, ...                ; Number of array elements
    call TestWavy               ; -> AL=[0,1]
    mov  [REZ], al

    ...

  ; IN (cx,si) OUT (al) MOD (ah,bx,cx,dx,si,di,bp)
  TestWavy:
    sub  cx, 1
    jbe  .fine                  ; In case of 0 or 1 array elements
    cld                         ; Clear DF so LODSW will SI++
    mov  bp, cx                 ;         and STOSB will DI++
    lea  di, [si+bp]            ; Address of the last element
    mov  al, [di]
    mov  cx, 8
    rep stosb
  .more:
    lodsw                       ; Load 8 elements
    xchg dx, ax                 ; `mov dx, ax`
    lodsw
    xchg cx, ax                 ; `mov cx, ax`
    lodsw
    xchg bx, ax                 ; `mov bx, ax`
    lodsw
    cmp  dl, dh                 ; Check 4 rising edges
    jg   .wrong
    cmp  cl, ch
    jg   .wrong
    cmp  bl, bh
    jg   .wrong
    cmp  al, ah
    jg   .wrong
    cmp  dh, cl                 ; Check 4 falling edges
    jl   .wrong
    cmp  ch, bl
    jl   .wrong
    cmp  bh, al
    jl   .wrong
    cmp  ah, [si]
    jl   .wrong
    sub  bp, 8
    ja   .more
  .fine:
    mov  al, 1
    ret
  .wrong:
    mov  al, 0
    ret
  ```

Comment: Loading each element twice (once with `lodsb`, again with `cmp al,[si]`) seems inefficient.  It might be saving code-size, but the reason that's more efficient on 8086 is minimizing memory accesses.  It's also good for simplicity for beginners, but I wonder if this could be optimized better for 8086.  Probably if you were optimizing, you'd `lodsw` / `cmp al, ah`, then possibly `cmp ah, [si]`.

Comment: Your version with 2 passes over the array is interesting, and might be competitive on 8088 even though it still loads every byte twice.  It's bad on 8086 where one of the passes is misaligned words, so every `lodsw` takes two memory bus cycles.  Using the last 2 bytes as a sentinel is fun if you're trying to avoid the `loop` instruction, although it's efficient on 8086.  Also, the .fine/.wrong code could be optimized to `cmp` / `sbb al,al` to return 0 / -1, maybe requiring swapping the meaning of 0 / non-zero return values.

Comment: The later version with `lodsw` / `xchg` is more along the lines I was thinking.  Nice, unrolling allows really good use of byte regs across words, and amortizing that extra byte load vs. keeping a value around for the next iteration.

Comment: With SSE2 SIMD you might do something like `movdqu` and `palignr` or `psrldq` to feed a `pcmpgtb` / `pmovmskb` / scalar cmp to check that the pattern is what it should be.  Depending on the CPU (fast unaligned SIMD loads or not) you might check scalar at the boundary, or SSSE3 `palignr` to make get unaligned vectors with data from two chunks instead of overlapping by 1 byte.